# Existence of invariant distribution for vector-valued AR(1) series

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

Vector-valued AR(1) time series: $$Y_n=AY_{n-1}+\varepsilon_n,$$

where $ \varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,...$ are i.i.d $\mathcal{N}(0,M)$, $M$- strictly positive definite

Prove that an invariant distribution exists $\iff$ $A^n→0$ as $n→\infty$

I know that for scalar-valued AR(1): $X_n=\rho X_{n-1}+\varepsilon,$ where $\varepsilon\in\mathcal{N}(\mu,\tau^2)$ invariant distribution exists (and unique) when $|\rho|<1, \mu=0,Var(X)=\frac{\tau^2}{1-\rho^2}.$ How can i implement this knowlege to prove the criterion of invariant distribution existence for vector-valued AR(1)?